# How do I stop the labels for my graph from being inside the graph?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I created a function to produce a spider/radar plot but I've run into an error.

**This line is giving me trouble:**

```
ax.set_thetagrids(angles * 180/np.pi, labels = labels, color='blue', frac=1.5)
```

According to the documentation, "*frac* is the fraction of the polar axes radius at which to
place the label (1 is the edge). e.g., 1.05 is outside the axes
and 0.95 is inside the axes."

However, even though I set frac=1.5, the labels are still overlapping with the plot itself. 
[This is an example of a plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXrBz.png)

=========================================================================

Here is the entire function definition:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def make_radar_chart(name, stats, labels, plot_markers = markers, plot_str_markers = str_markers):
    markers = [1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    str_markers = ["",'', "", '', "", '', "", "", "", '']
    labels = np.array(labels)

    angles = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, len(labels), endpoint=False)
    stats = np.concatenate((stats,[stats[0]]))
    angles = np.concatenate((angles,[angles[0]]))

    fig= plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
    ax.plot(angles, stats, 'green', linewidth=1)
    ax.fill(angles, stats, 'green', alpha=0.25)
    ax.set_thetagrids(angles * 180/np.pi, labels = labels, color='blue', frac=1.5)
    plt.yticks(markers)
    plt.yticks([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], ["",'','3','',"5","",'7','',''], color="grey", size=7)
    ax.set_title(name)
    ax.grid(True)
    return plt.show()
```

Comment: I think it also has to do how long is the label. Try using a smaller label (less characters) to see the difference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out the [What's new in matplotlib 2.1](https://matplotlib.org/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_2.1.0.html#enhancements-to-polar-plot) where it says:

> [...] Additionally, tick labels now obey the padding settings that previously only worked on Cartesian plots. Consequently, the `frac` argument to `PolarAxes.set_thetagrids` is no longer applied. Tick padding can be modified with the `pad` argument to `Axes.tick_params` or `Axis.set_tick_params`.